# Having trouble with Jquery's toggleClass

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggleclass

I have been trying to get toggleClass to work so a click will change the color of the box, but this doesn't seem to work. Here is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".box").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

```css
.box{
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
  background: red;
  top: 10em;
}   
.open{
  background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/2artbp7z/

Answer (score 0):

Try this in CSS? Could be specificity issue. Try this:

```css
.box.open {
    background: blue;
}
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".box").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
  background: red;
  top: 10em;
}   
.box.open {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! So do i have to specify for every element that i want changed? I thought i could just make the changes to the class.

Comment: I guess so. But this is the second option you need to take. I don't know why your original code shouldn't work. It should work that way it is. `:)` To answer your question, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Try add event.preventDefault(); to prevent the click event been fired multiple times.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("open");
    });
});
```

Comment: I am sure there's no event handlers registered when you click on a `<div>`! `:P`

Comment: This also worked! So why did everyone else not need this line of code?

Comment: I don't know the structure of your DOM, whether the ".box" element have any child element or not. Generally, an event triggered by a child element would bubble up to its parent.